# CGAffineTransformScale and Animation not working as expected

Tags: ios, core-animation, transformation

I am creating a storybook app, which is essentially as series of short animations. Each "page turn" is just a short animation where the page zooms out. For **page1**, the animation works as expected, however, for **page2**, if I call the action page2 while the first animation is still in progress, it seems to jump in right where **page1** is at that moment, ignoring it's own duration, delay, etc.

Ideally, I'd like the animation **page2** to play as it's own zoom out, the same way, no matter when it is called, what might I change in this code.

```
-(IBAction) page1
{
    pageImageNext.bounds = CGRectMake(-240, -370, 1200, 800);

    [UIImageView animateWithDuration:7.5 delay:2.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedDuration |
                                                            UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
        CGAffineTransform zoom = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, .4, .4); 
        self.pageImageNext.center = CGPointMake(240,160);
        self.pageImageNext.transform = zoom;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
}

-(IBAction) page2
{
    pageImageNext.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"page2.jpg"];
    pageImageNext.bounds = CGRectMake(-240, -370, 1200, 800);

    [UIImageView animateWithDuration:7.5 delay:6.0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedDuration |
                                                            UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | 
                                                            UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations: ^{
        CGAffineTransform zoom2 = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, .4, .4);    
        self.pageImageNext.center = CGPointMake(240,160);
        self.pageImageNext.transform = zoom2;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
}
```

In addition the line **`pageImageNext.bounds = CGRectMake(-240, -370, 1200, 800);`** seems to have no effect in **page2**, as it isn't resizing the `UImageView`, but rather seems to "inherit" it's current size from the previous transformation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I haven't actually figured out what was going wrong in the above, though I have figured out that by using Core Animation, I do get the correct effect, by using this code in each `IBAction`:

```
pageImageNext.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"page1.jpg"];
pageImageNext.bounds = CGRectMake(-240, -470, 1200, 800);

CABasicAnimation *zoomOut = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
zoomOut.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()+4;
zoomOut.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.4];
zoomOut.duration = 8.0;
zoomOut.fillMode=kCAFillModeForwards;
zoomOut.removedOnCompletion=NO;
[pageImageNext.layer addAnimation:zoomOut forKey:@"zoomOut"];
```